# word document issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016

In SharePoint 2016, one of the user is having issue where the user tries to open a word document and it automatically checks-out the document and never opens it.

Other users are not having this issue.

The auto-checkout functionality on the document is disabled and user is not trying to edit the document.

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, no similar situation occurred in SharePoint 2016.

**It is recommended that you perform the following troubleshooting:**

1. View the user's permissions
2. Whether some custom settings are set, such as javascript or json.
3. Test in other Document libraries to check whether the user still has the check-out operation.
4. You could install **[the latest SharePoint 2016 patch package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates)**.